# mongodb aggregation - group with last on date

Tags: mongodb, max, aggregation-framework, aggregate

My mongodb collection include 3 fields: number, date, type.
What I want to know is how much documents includes the most recent date for their number and has type=3. In pasudo code what I am trying to find will look like this:

```
Set<String> numbers; //set includes the numbers in the documents
int result = 0;
for each (String thisNumber: numbers)
{
    //find all the documents with this number
    List<Document> documentsWithThisNumber = collection.find({number: "$thisNumber"});
    //find the one with the most recent date with this number
    documentsWithThisNumber = documentsWithThisNumber.sort();
    Document recentDate = documentsWithThisNumber.get(documentsWithThisNumber.size()-1);
    //if this recent document has type 3 we want to count it
    if (recentDate.getType()==3)
        result++;
}
```

I tried to build a query that will group by the number, and take the last/max date on each number and match the ones their type equal to 3. Since the group can contain only accumulators, and I needed to save the "type" field also for the match, I used the "first" accumulator for the "type" field. I assumed that after it will pick up the document with recent event for each number, this accumulator will just bring me the type of this document.
My query was:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$group: {_id: {"number" : "$number"}, "recentDate" : {$max : "$date"}, 
"recentType" : {$first : "$type"}}},
{$match: {"recentType" : 3}},
{$count: "Qty"}
],{allowDiskUse: true});
```

The result of this query is wrong, and in addition I discovered that if I switch the $max to $min/$first/$last or if I move it after the "recentType"- I still get the same wrong result, what cause me to think that the "recentDate" doesn't effects the query at all.

Maybe someone has an idea how to build such a query?

Comment: What do you mean by *"How many(sic) documents for the recent date?"*. What is a "date"? Is it "today"? Is it "within the last hour?". A date is typically stored with what represents a timestamp value, which essentially is precise to the millisecond. So unless that date value itself is "grouped" within some timeframe, then the likelihood of any two documents sharing the same exact "timestamp" is infinitesimal. At any rate, it's not "one query" but "two". One to get the "recent date" and the other to actually return data based on that.

Comment: Ok, I think I was misunderstood. I will try to explain again my question: First, the date is an iso date so 2 documents can share the same date, but lets assume in order to simplify the query that they can't and dates are unique . Second, this is what I am interested: each number can have several documents, with different/equal dates and types, I want to look on the document with the biggest date, if this document has type equal to 3 - I want to add it to the count, if it doesn't - to skip to the next number.

Comment: Try `db.collection.aggregate([ {$sort:{number:1, date:1}}, {$group: {_id: {"number" : "$number"}, "recent" : {$last: {date:"$$ROOT.date", type:"$$ROOT.type"}}}}, {$match: {"recent.type" : 3}}, {$count: "Qty"}
 ]);`

Comment: Yes! This works for me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Given records that look like this:

```
var r = [
     { number: 12, type: 2, date: new ISODate("2017-10-30") }
     ,{ number: 10, type: 2, date: new ISODate("2017-10-20") }
     ,{ number: 12, type: 3, date: new ISODate("2017-10-30") }
     ,{ number: 12, type: 3, date: new ISODate("2017-10-30") }
     ,{ number: 12, type: 3, date: new ISODate("2017-10-30") }
     ,{ number: 12, type: 3, date: new ISODate("2017-10-28") }
     ,{ number: 12, type: 3, date: new ISODate("2017-10-15") }
     ,{ number: 10, type: 3, date: new ISODate("2017-10-15") }
     ,{ number: 10, type: 3, date: new ISODate("2017-10-15") }
     ,{ number: 10, type: 3, date: new ISODate("2017-10-18") }
     ,{ number: 10, type: 3, date: new ISODate("2017-10-18") }
     ,{ number: 10, type: 3, date: new ISODate("2017-10-19") }
     ,{ number: 10, type: 3, date: new ISODate("2017-10-19") }
     ,{ number: 10, type: 3, date: new ISODate("2017-10-11") }
     ];

db.foo.insert(r);
```

Then this pipeline may do the trick.  As Neil points out, you have to first get the number of docs with the same number before you reorg the material to get the most recent date:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$match: {"type": 3}}
,{$group: {_id: {number: "$number", date: "$date"}, n: {$sum:1} }}
,{$sort: {"_id.date": -1}}
,{$group: {_id: "$_id.number", date: {$first: "$_id.date"}, n: {$first: "$n"} }}
            ]);

{ "_id" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2017-10-19T00:00:00Z"), "n" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 12, "date" : ISODate("2017-10-30T00:00:00Z"), "n" : 3 }
```

Comment: I don't understand your query. First, I am looking for only one number at the end, and the result of your query is a list of numbers. Second, if I have 2 documents to number "10": the recent one with type "2" and the earlier with type "3" - in this case I don't want to add to my count, because the recent document is with type "2" not "3". So I can't start with a match to type "3" documents, because then I will loose the type "2" document, and don't know that the type "3" document is the one with the recent date for number "10".